# python search two keys in dict from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
{
    "neighbors": [
        {
            "5142_2_IpIf1002": "10.10.160.141",
            "8700_ipif_1002": "10.10.160.142"
        },
        {
            "5142_2_IpIf1006": "10.10.160.181",
            "5170_ipif_1006": "10.10.160.182"
        },
        {
            "5160_1_IpIf1005": "10.10.160.177",
            "5170_ipif_1005": "10.10.160.178"
        },
        {
            "5160_1_IpIf3337": "10.10.160.125",
            "8700_IpIf3337": "10.10.160.126"
        },
        {
            "8700_ipif_1001": "10.10.160.129",
            "5160_1_IpIf1001": "10.10.160.130"
        },
        {
            "8700_ipif_1003": "10.10.160.169",
            "5170_ipif_1003": "10.10.160.170"
        },
        {
            "8700_ipif_1004": "10.10.160.173",
            "5170_ipif_1004": "10.10.160.174"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following list:

```
hostnames = ['8700', '5170', '5142_2']
```

In the above dict I only look for the entries that contain at least two of the list elements to find the LLDP neighbors for the path that i want to find in the network.

```
import json

hostnames = ['8700', '5170', '5142_2']

with open('ip_list.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for element in data["neighbors"]:
    for h in hostnames:
        if h in str(element.keys()):
            print('{} - {}'.format(element.keys(), element.values()))
```

This code solves this for one entry in the "element" dict but that's not what i need.

So in this case i want the program to only print out the following entries from the json file:

```
"5142_2_IpIf1002": "10.10.160.141",
"8700_ipif_1002": "10.10.160.142"

"5142_2_IpIf1006": "10.10.160.181",
"5170_ipif_1006": "10.10.160.182"

"8700_ipif_1003": "10.10.160.169",
"5170_ipif_1003": "10.10.160.170"

"8700_ipif_1004": "10.10.160.173",
"5170_ipif_1004": "10.10.160.174"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I want to print only the entries from the JSON file that contain at least two entries from the list with the hostnames. And I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

for element in data["neighbors"]:
    for h1, h2 in itertools.combinations(hostnames, 2):
        if h1 in str(element.keys()) and h2 in str(element.keys()):
            print('{} - {}'.format(element.keys(), element.values()))
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['5142_2_IpIf1002', '8700_ipif_1002']) - dict_values(['10.10.160.141', '10.10.160.142'])
dict_keys(['5142_2_IpIf1006', '5170_ipif_1006']) - dict_values(['10.10.160.181', '10.10.160.182'])
dict_keys(['8700_ipif_1003', '5170_ipif_1003']) - dict_values(['10.10.160.169', '10.10.160.170'])
dict_keys(['8700_ipif_1004', '5170_ipif_1004']) - dict_values(['10.10.160.173', '10.10.160.174'])
```